# Regex adding to filename by find replace (Java/ECMA script regex)

Tags: regex, replacement, append

I am trying to append to a filename with regex replace.This can be done by many ways for sure but i need to do it with regex, Need select filename and replace it with filename+newtext

so in example i should be able to replace all these three lines with one fixed regex.

```
apple.txt
banana.zip
abc.123.rar
```

into

```
apple.txt newtext
banana.zip newtext
123.abc.rar newtext
```

A more realized example:

```
randomfilename.randomtextension
```

replaced to `WinRAR.exe d "randomfilename.randomtextension" *.3ds *fbx *obj *.txt *.url`

The interface i am using for regex is this
[image]

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: it s the java script ECMAScript regex

Comment: Then ask the question at https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: sure will do, thnx